# set default value to edit text and use the value while connecting

Tags: android, android-edittext

How to set default value to an edit text field in android and use that value when a button is clicked and a URL was given to open on click and that above edit text value will be validated while connecting to the URL.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

***Try like this:***

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewbyId(R.id.edittext);
     editText.setText("DefaultValue");
}
```

Comment: there is a certificate file and private key file which have to be entered while connecting to 192.168.10.1 while doing provisioning. So I am supposed to put those two text files as hard coded ones so that user of android app will not be able to change them but when he clicks on "submit" those certificate and private key files needed to be sent for validation.

Answer (score 1):

Add in xml layout file

```
android:text="defaultVal"
```

In onClick method or constructor/init method in java

```
editText.setText("DefaultValue");
```

Comment: there is a certificate file and private key file which have to be entered while connecting to 192.168.10.1 while doing provisioning. So I am supposed to put those two text files as hard coded ones so that user of android app will not be able to change them but when he clicks on "submit" those certificate and private key files needed to be sent for validation.

Comment: Read those files & get values from files if you need that. What are the types of files?

Comment: those files are unique for "Thing" we create in amazon AWS IOT management console. for every thing, there will be one unique private key and certificate which are needed to be installed on device while provisioning. Till now this process has been going on in web interface. Now I am supposed to do in an android app where thing name will be visible to user and the certificate and private key shouldnt be entered by him. They r supposed to be hard coded but  app  must use them when user clicks on submit button while connecting to 192.168.10.1